# keras ImageDataGenerator flow_from_directory generated data

Tags: keras

I'm trying to see the result of using *ImageDataGenerator* for data augmentation.
Keras reads the data but it seems that it doesn't perform any generation on them. I get as output:

> Found 32 images belonging to 1 classes.

but no generated images are saved in the directory I mentioned in *save_to_dir* parameter of flow_from_directory method.

Here my code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator,  array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

#the path of images to apply augmentation on them
images_path='train'
#create an instance of ImageDataGenerator
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.2,
        height_shift_range=0.2)
datagen.flow_from_directory(directory=images_path, target_size=(480,752),color_mode='grayscale', class_mode=None, save_to_dir='saved',save_prefix='keras_')
img = load_img('train/images/photon10.png')
x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)
datagen.flow(x,batch_size=1,save_to_dir='saved',save_format='png')
```

I even tried to perform augmentation on one image and it wasn't saved.

What could be the reason? I'm a starter with Keras.

Note: class mode is None because I don't have a specific category.

Comment: Have you made sure your images are in a subdirectory of `images_path`?

Answer (score 1):

`flow_from_directory()` returns a `DirectoryIterator`. The files are not saved until you iterate over this iterator.

For example,

```
iterator = datagen.flow_from_directory(...)
next(iterator)
```

will save a batch of augmented images to `save_to_dir`. You can also use a for loop over the iterator to control how many images will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Its only a declaration, you must use that generator, for example, `.next()`

```
datagen.next()
```

then you will see images in `saved`